# 'Cannot read property '' of undefined' EJS doesn't render variable , allthough it is defined

Tags: json, node.js, express, undefined, ejs

this is driving me nuts , please assist me:
I'm using latest v of node.js with express , mongo and EJS
The interesting fact is the **website still works** just fine after the following error in console:

```
Cannot read property 'parent_category_id' of undefined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (E:\BITBUCKET repos\demo nodeJS\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:485:12), <anonymous>:20:27)
at returnedFn (E:\BITBUCKET repos\demo nodeJS\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:514:17)
at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (E:\BITBUCKET repos\demo nodeJS\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:358:31)
at View.render (E:\BITBUCKET repos\demo nodeJS\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:126:8)
at tryRender (E:\BITBUCKET repos\demo nodeJS\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:639:10)
at EventEmitter.render (E:\BITBUCKET repos\demo nodeJS\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:591:3)
at ServerResponse.render (E:\BITBUCKET repos\demo nodeJS\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:961:7)
at E:\BITBUCKET repos\demo AndreiRadulescu nodeJS\Router.js:108:12
at handleCallback (E:\BITBUCKET repos\demo nodeJS\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:96:12)
at E:\BITBUCKET repos\demo
```

nodeJS\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:851:16

My Router :

```
router.get(
'/:categ/:subCateg' ,
function ( req , res )
{
    var subC  = req.params.subCateg;
    var categ = req.params.categ;
    req.app.locals.db.collection( "categories" )
       .find
       (
           { categories : { $elemMatch : { id : subC } } }
       )
       //gets only the categories we're interested in
       .map( function ( u ) { return u.categories[ 0 ] } )
       .toArray
       (
           function ( err , docs )
           {
               var toSend = docs[ 0 ];
               //res.json( toSend );
               res.render(
                   "subCategs" , {
                       _     : _ ,
                       docs : toSend ,
                       ...
```

The result from res.json(toSend) is what I expect :

[image: res.json()]

As I mentioned before ,allmost everything is working despite the error  !!
It breaks though when getting the /api/ with the same error.

I suspect there might be an issue with my other routes:

```
router.get(
    '/:root/:topC/:prods' , function ( req , res )...

router.get(
'/:root/:topC/:subC/:prodId' ,function ( req , res )...

router.get(
'/api/:SOAPmethod' , function ( req , res ) ...

GET /
GET /mens/mens-clothing
GET /mens/mens-clothing/mens-clothing-suits
GET /mens/mens-clothing/mens-clothing-suits/25604524
GET /api/getall
TypeError: E:\BITBUCKET repos\demo nodeJS\views\subCategs.ejs:8
    6|     <title><%=title%></title>
    7|     <style>
 >> 8|         #<%=docs["parent_category_id"]%>
    9|         {
   10|             background: rgba(178, 190, 255, 0.9)
   11|         ;

Cannot read property 'parent_category_id' of undefined............
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `docs` isn't defined.  What makes you think it is defined?

Comment: res.json(toSend) tells me it is defined?